# Random sampling in parallel R programming for NBClust

Tags: r, parallel-processing, cluster-analysis

I have a big dataframe with 2.5 million rows (and 7 or 8 relevant columns), and I'm trying to use the `NBClust` R package to try to figure out how many clusters the data has. I'm only using 1.9 million rows for this, which fullfill a condition. Since that many rows are still way too much for NBClust and my PC, I was thinking I'll take random subsections of the data frame with `dplyr::sample_frac`. 0.1% of the data is 1900 rows, I was thinking I'll do NBClust on that 8 times (2 for each of my CPU core). My problem is, that based on the results it seems like inside the foreach the randomly sampled 1900 rows are the same each time. I obviously want them to be different each time. Here is my code:

```
cl <- makeCluster(NumberOfCluster)
registerDoSNOW(cl)
noenergy.scaled.results <- foreach(i = 1:8, .combine = "rbind", .packages = c("dplyr", "NbClust")) %dopar% {
  set.seed(i)
  noenergy.scaled.sampled <- sample_frac(clustering69.noenergy.scaled, 0.001)
  noenergy.scaled.res<-NbClust(noenergy.scaled.sampled, distance = "euclidean", min.nc=2, max.nc=8, 
                        method = "kmeans", index = "all")
  return(noenergy.scaled.res)
}
stopCluster(cl)

bestpartition.noenergy.scaled <- data.frame(noenergy.scaled.results[,4])
summary(bestpartition.noenergy.scaled) #3 result for 3 cluster, 5 result for 2 cluster
```

I wrote the set.seed(i) part after I saw the first results, but it seems like it did not have any effect.

(The variable names are like that because I also wanna try this without scaling, plus with an extra (energy related) column, but I have that column in 2 different not convertible unit.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why it's not working for you. Using `set.seed(i)` in `foreach` with `%dopar%` works for me. Can you try:

```
NP <- lapply( 1:5, function(xx) { set.seed(xx)
                                  sample_frac(mtcars,0.1) })  # single-core

library(doParallel) # setting up parallel
library(foreach)
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())
registerDoParallel(cl)

P <- foreach(i=1:5, .packages = c("dplyr")) %dopar% { set.seed(i)
                                                     sample_frac(mtcars,0.1)} # parallel equivalent
stopCluster(cl)

identical(P,NP)
[1] TRUE
```

I get `TRUE` for this evaluation. What do you get?